# Do I need a hammer drill to install brackets for drapes on a brick wall?

Tags: walls, brick, drill

I want to put up brackets for drapes. I have a masonry bit, but are using a simple (and possible cheap) cordless drill.  I can seem to penetrate the brick.  Do I need a hammer drill to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Petty much going to need a hammer drill for brick. You could try going into the mortar, but it sounds like you already dulled your bit. Try a fresh bit going into the mortar joint but don't expect superior pull-out strength.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the brick, a drill bit for glass will go through brick faster, easier than standard carbide bits. Sometimes just with a regular drill, it is worth a try.

[image: drill bits]